# Push files to Jenkins workspace from remote location

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm currently using Jenkins to trigger tests via an external test system and aggregate results. This system follows a typical master slave relationship and stores results, logs, and other files generated from these tests on the slave machine.

Is there a way to push these files from the test slave to the Jenkins workspace while the job is running? This way they can be available to the developer with the test results on job completion.

Comment: Create a job step in jenkins to do a scp or rsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a pull rather than a push. You would have Jenkins job pull the files in any method you prefer (scp, rsync, wget etc).

Jenkins workspace locations are typically randomised folders based on the job name with a hash/incrementor number in the path, so a Push would be inadvisable.

Comment: I wanted to push because where the files are stored on the slave are semi-randomized and the slave running the tests is determined independent of Jenkins. So it's just as hard to pull from Jenkins as it is to push to Jenkins. 

That being said, you do appear to be right that there isn't a great way to push to Jenkins so I'm planning on pushing to a more structured intermediate location then pulling from Jenkins. Its a bit roundabout but it should serve its purpose for the time being.

Comment: If the jobs are being executed in the same 'pipeline', then perhaps the stash/unstash feature may assist instead?
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build